# Check Boxes in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a gridview with a list of names and beside them checkboxes for if they are still teaching.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Faculty Name" DataField="faculty_name" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No Longer Teaching" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate >
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbTeaching" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

I need to know if the checkbox has been checked to update the database however when I test it the checkboxes are never recognized. Here's my code for getting the checkbox data.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
     {
         CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("cbTeaching");
         if (cb != null)
         {
             if(cb.Checked==true)
             Label1.Text = "found";
         }
     }
```

Now Label1 never changes so I know that cb is always null. I've looked up multipule examples and they all say to do some slight variation of this.

Comment: have you debugged it? is `cb` always null?

Comment: yes, I've even ran a loop to get all of the controls on the page and cbTeaching doesn't show up. Just the gridview. @DrewJordan

Comment: In what context is your foreach loop executed? Can you show the surrounding code to see what event is being handled? If you put a breakpoint in the loop, is the code called at all?